# Callback executed too early

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, foreach, callback

I'm struggling with an issue I can't get around.

I'm using NodeJS to request data from Rest API´s. For this program I first retrieve an array of data, then I request some details from another endpoint based on an id from the first array.

I use a foreach loop inside the first function call with callback, and then another function call within the foreach loop to get the details.

What I experience is that the second function does callback before the response is retrieved.

I have managed to reproduce the issue with the following example code:

```
console.log('Program start')

// Executing program
getFirstname(function(person) {

    person.forEach(firstname => {

        getSurname(firstname.id, function(lastname) {
            console.log(`${firstname.value} ${lastname}`)
        });

    });
})

// Emulating REST API´s
function getFirstname(callback) {

    console.log('Returning list of firstnames')

    let data = [
        {id: 0, value: 'John'},
        {id: 2, value: 'Andy'},
        {id: 3, value: 'Jimmy'},
        {id: 4, value: 'Alex'},
        {id: 0, value: 'John'},
        {id: 2, value: 'Andy'},
        {id: 3, value: 'Jimmy'},
        {id: 4, value: 'Alex'},
        {id: 0, value: 'John'},
        {id: 2, value: 'Andy'},
        {id: 3, value: 'Jimmy'},
        {id: 4, value: 'Alex'},
        {id: 0, value: 'John'},
        {id: 2, value: 'Andy'},
        {id: 3, value: 'Jimmy'},
        {id: 4, value: 'Alex'},
        {id: 0, value: 'John'},
        {id: 2, value: 'Andy'},
        {id: 3, value: 'Jimmy'},
        {id: 4, value: 'Alex'},
        {id: 0, value: 'John'},
        {id: 2, value: 'Andy'},
        {id: 3, value: 'Jimmy'},
        {id: 4, value: 'Alex'},
        {id: 0, value: 'John'},
        {id: 2, value: 'Andy'},
        {id: 3, value: 'Jimmy'},
        {id: 4, value: 'Alex'},
        {id: 0, value: 'John'},
        {id: 2, value: 'Andy'},
        {id: 3, value: 'Jimmy'},
        {id: 4, value: 'Alex'},
        {id: 0, value: 'John'},
        {id: 2, value: 'Andy'},
        {id: 3, value: 'Jimmy'},
        {id: 4, value: 'Alex'},
        {id: 0, value: 'John'},
        {id: 2, value: 'Andy'},
        {id: 3, value: 'Jimmy'},
        {id: 4, value: 'Alex'},
    ]

    callback(data);
}

function getSurname(id, callback) {

    console.log(`Querying for lastname id ${id}`)

    let data = [
        'Andersen',
        'Johsen',
        'Falon',
        'Alexander',
    ]

    setTimeout(() => {
        callback(data[id]);
    }, 2000);
}
```

Here is the result of the program:

```
Program start
Returning list of firstnames
Querying for lastname id 0
Querying for lastname id 2
Querying for lastname id 3
Querying for lastname id 4
Querying for lastname id 0
Querying for lastname id 2
Querying for lastname id 3
Querying for lastname id 4
Querying for lastname id 0
Querying for lastname id 2
Querying for lastname id 3
Querying for lastname id 4
Querying for lastname id 0
Querying for lastname id 2
Querying for lastname id 3
Querying for lastname id 4
Querying for lastname id 0
Querying for lastname id 2
Querying for lastname id 3
Querying for lastname id 4
Querying for lastname id 0
Querying for lastname id 2
Querying for lastname id 3
Querying for lastname id 4
Querying for lastname id 0
Querying for lastname id 2
Querying for lastname id 3
Querying for lastname id 4
Querying for lastname id 0
Querying for lastname id 2
Querying for lastname id 3
Querying for lastname id 4
Querying for lastname id 0
Querying for lastname id 2
Querying for lastname id 3
Querying for lastname id 4
Querying for lastname id 0
Querying for lastname id 2
Querying for lastname id 3
Querying for lastname id 4
John Andersen
Andy Falon
Jimmy Alexander
Alex undefined
John Andersen
Andy Falon
Jimmy Alexander
Alex undefined
John Andersen
Andy Falon
Jimmy Alexander
Alex undefined
John Andersen
Andy Falon
Jimmy Alexander
Alex undefined
John Andersen
Andy Falon
Jimmy Alexander
Alex undefined
John Andersen
Andy Falon
Jimmy Alexander
Alex undefined
John Andersen
Andy Falon
Jimmy Alexander
Alex undefined
John Andersen
Andy Falon
Jimmy Alexander
Alex undefined
John Andersen
Andy Falon
Jimmy Alexander
Alex undefined
John Andersen
Andy Falon
Jimmy Alexander
Alex undefined
```

As you can see, there are several records with `undefined` value. Also I have added a `setTimeout` to emulate that each rest call takes a few seconds. What happens is that all the queries are fired off instantly, then it goes 2 seconds before all the responses return simultaneous.

I would expect this to wait for each second rest call and then return the result.

How can I solve this issue?

Best regards,
Christian

Answer (score 3):

The reason you have `undefined` is because your `data` array has length of `4` (indices go from **0 to 3**) but your `id`'s range from 0 to **4**.  Which means that when you reference `data[4]` you get `undefined`.

Comment: Your right. That was actually a typo in the example code, but I have this problem with my real code.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your callbacks. The data, however is incorrect. See below:

```
function getSurname(id, callback) {

    console.log(`Querying for lastname id ${id}`)

    let data = [
        'Andersen',
        'Johsen',
        'Falon',
        'Alexander',
    ]

    setTimeout(() => {
        callback(data[id]);
    }, 2000);
}
```

Everytime `Alex` is called, you're passing id `4` for use in your `data` array. Remember that array's are `0` based so `data[4] = undefined`...

Comment: Ref comment on previous answer. I can see I did a typo there and that my example actually works. This does not solve the problem in my real code :(

Comment: @chranmat No worries. Can you post your actual code please?